# How do I align text to the middle of an element with CSS in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, centering, text-alignment

I am using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts) alerts and this is my success alert message:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="UploadSuccess">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <strong>Congrats!</strong> You have successfully did it!.
</div>
```

And the result is:

[image: Resulting image of above HTML]

As you'll can see that the text alignment is at the top of the `<div>`. So, how would II align it to the middle?

I have tried using `padding-top` and `vertical-align:middle` but neither works (I end up with the same result).

What do I need to do to change the vertical alignment of the text?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make the `line-height` of the div the same as the `height` of the div, eg:

```
#UploadSuccess { height: 20px; line-height: 20px; }
```

This will only work if you have one line of text.

Answer (score 10):

Trying to vertically center text text is a common issue. Normally this wouldn't work on normal boxes, but you can force it to work with vertical align:

```
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
```

However this will not work in IE7 and lower.

If you are sure the text you want to display you could use line-height to fake the effect like this:

```
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px; /* same as height */
```

This way works cross browser and has support up to IE5.5 I believe. If this is not an option I'm afraid you're out of luck (it can't be done).

As a side note that error message suffers from bad grammar, it should be "Congratulations! You have successfully done it.".

Comment: @sg3s-Yes,you're right and I am still in testing the alerts and ofcourse the grammar is bad.I will make use the correct one.

Answer (score 10):

Make it easier ;) ! Try to use alert-block ! That works fine with latest Bootstrap version !

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-success" id="UploadSuccess">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <strong>Congrats!</strong> You have successfully did it!.
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Upload image somewhere else and add link with your post.

Comment: Nice idea, sorry ^^ ! Here you are !