# How to vertically center a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns (`div { float: left; }`, as you  may know) in the Bootstrap Structure. The problem is to make the content inside one `div` go the middle (vertical). So, it doesn't matter the height of the second columns, the second column will always be on the middle.

It is not an line of text. In my case will be an image and a title. Two blocks of elements.

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/almino_melo/L4rK5/.

I tried to put another `div` inside it with `display: table;` rule and then another one with `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't link to JSFiddles except to support your question. Your question needs to be answerable without opening any external links; as it stands nobody can answer this without first opening the JSFiddle.

Comment: if you have one line of text you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061339/how-do-i-align-text-to-the-middle-of-an-element-with-css-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: I'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/L4rK5/9/ , it does what you ask but does seem really rather crude, note the change in the html div structure as well as the following css rules.

```
.text-center{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```